# How can I get the Windows 7 Manage menu back?

Tags: windows-7, mmc

My computer is running Windows 7. I don't know how it happened, but my **Manage** menu — Computer > Manage — disappeared.

How can I bring it back? Or is there a shortcut for it?

Comment: Do you mean right click on Computer > manage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you use a registry cleaner lately?

This article was posted for XP but may help solve your issue if you feel comfortable about editing the registry

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/manage.htm

> The Manage command will become unavailable in one of these cases:
>
> Case 1: The following registry key is missing
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ CLSID \ {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} \ shell \ Manage
>
> Case 2: "Manage" command is disabled by Group Policy
>   "NoManageMyComputerVerb" Policy disables the Manage item on the My Computer / Explorer context menu. It's set under one of the following registry keys:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Policies \ Explorer
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Policies \ Explorer
>
> You would need to delete the "NoManageMyComputerVerb" value

If you have W7 Pro or Ultimate you can use [GPEDIT](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Use_Gpedit_in_Windows_7_38621793),  Go to:

User Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Windows
Explorer. Look in the right pane for "Hides the Manage item on the Windows
Explorer context menu". Double click this item and make sure its set to Not
Configured.
.

Comment: Well all credit to the very long answer, and I just answered the second bit. +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

`Computer Management`, under `Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools`.

Comment: +1, it was a two part question, a fix and a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was a policy for disabling that menu item. That's why I love this site so much. Learning every day :-)